# Joomla system plugin to run only if specific component

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla system plugin. It is running on every pageload, but I want it to run only with specific component. I have these functions on it:

```
function __construct( $s, $c ) {}
function onAfterRoute() {} 
function onAfterDispatch() {}
```

Any solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: If your plugin only needs to run on a component, maybe its code should be in the component itself. Otherwise go for @MatthewBaker's answer, place the code at the very top and no events will get triggered; or place it within each function.

Comment: The problem is that if he really needs it  onAfterDispatch that means that it is needed before the component starts. That's the real question I guess, why is it that this is a system plugin and not a component plugin?  Are there more appropriate events later on in the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Joomla!'s [JRequest getVar() function](http://docs.joomla.org/API17%3aJRequest%3a%3agetVar) and fetch the *option* parameter.

`JRequest::getVar('option')`

If called on the homepage for instance the value "*com_content*" would be returned.

So to help control whether a plugin should run it's functions perform a simple IF Statement like the one below.

```
<?php
    if( JRequest::getVar('option') === 'com_mycomponent') {
       // Run script
    }
?>
```

**Alternative approach**

If you don't wish to use `JRequest` due to security concerns you can fetch the name of the active component using the menu component functions.

```
<?php
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu = $app->getMenu();
    $sActiveComponent = $menu->getActive()->component;

    if( sActiveComponent === 'com_mycomponent') {
       // Run script
    }
?>
```

Comment: There is no other option to not to call at all any code from plugin? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this pull request https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/1514. It adds some extra plugin parameters to include/exclude menu items or components from caching. This will get you started. Probably it would make sense to add this globally to every plugin as extra options like it is now with modules.

Answer (score 0):

Check the context (usually com_something.viewname) at the start of the plugin to prevent it running.